# Connecting to new Wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-core

I am using Ubuntu Core on the Intel Joule. I went through all of the setup and everything was fine. I connected to a wifi network and am able to SSH into the Joule. However, we just set up a new wifi network in the office specifically for this, and I cannot figure out how to switch to a new wifi network. The way I originally connected to the current network was just through the "first boot" configuration step.

Is there a way to switch to a different wifi network?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that you should be able to simply run `sudo console-conf`, which is that first-boot setup you've already gone through. But it doesn't support more complex networking setups, so a more thorough answer is:

The Ubuntu Core images utilize [netplan](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2016-July/039464.html), and uses the systemd-networkd backend for it. I don't have a Joule on hand, but I have my Dragon board here, and I used the first boot setup to configure a wired ethernet connection. Let me walk you through what I'd do with netplan to setup a wireless connection.

1. Modify `/etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml`. This is the file generated by console-conf on first boot. Since I configured the wired connection on first boot, mine looked like this:

   ```
   # This is the network config written by 'console-conf'
   network:
     ethernets:
       eth0:
         addresses: []
         dhcp4: true
     version: 2
   ```

   Since I wanted to enable wifi, I updated this file to this:

   ```
   # This is the network config written by 'console-conf'
   network:
     ethernets:
       eth0:
         addresses: []
         dhcp4: true
     wifis:
       wlan0:
         access-points:
           <access point name>:
             password: <password>
         dhcp4: true
     version: 2
   ```
2. Run `sudo netplan generate` to generate the necessary backend configuration for systemd-networkd.
3. Run `sudo netplan apply` to actually apply the new config.

You can run `networkctl` periodically and you'll see the interfaces come up.

Comment: I did attach a usb wifi card to my parallel desktop ubuntu machine and i did all config but after ```networkctl```shows:

```
3 wlx1062eb30a0f0  wlan               no-carrier  configuring
``` and stuck.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi not sure about Ubuntu Core (never used it myself), but did it come with `wpa-supplicant`? There are a number of packages you don't get which are required for WiFi functionality when installing a system as "server" and then converting to a "desktop" (as I had to do because the desktop install media refused to even get to the installation UI). So I basically installed Ubuntu server, it came with `netplan` and no bells and whistles and `wpa-supplicant` was one of the missing puzzle-pieces. That was installed alongside `cinnamon-desktop-environment`, though.

Comment: Had to do `systemctl daemon-reload` or I'd have wierd dhcp4 issues and state degraded status.