# can we do Bridge Networking for laptop wifi?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I want to create virtual machine on the top up of my laptop with the help of KVM. I have installed all the neccessory packages required for it.

I want to setup Bridge network so that my virtual machine will get the local ip  subnet.

Her is my /etc/network/interface file:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
         address 192.168.0.101
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         broadcast 192.168.0.255
         gateway 192.168.0.1
         dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
         bridge_ports wlp1s0
         bridge_stp off
         bridge_fd 0
         bridge_maxwait 0
```

But this configuration is not working as I am not able to access internet after this setup.. I am not able to figure out where is the problem.
Any suggestion please !!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  The reason I ask is that 17.10 does not follow the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/976464/etc-network-interfaces-is-ignored

Comment: Its Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: See http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/

Comment: Depends on the wireless card having support.  Many do not.