# Interfaces is ignored

Tags: networking

So, I installed server edition 16.04. 
Network manager is not installed.

```
> ~$ less /etc/network/interfaces

>#auto  enp3s0
>#iface lo inet loopback 
>iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

I have tried various combinations here, but with this spesifik config i can reboot and  lo still comes up. 
Seems that no matter what I set i etc/network/interfaceses, it is ignored and the computer brings up lo and enp3s0 on every boot.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The loopback interface, lo, is *supposed* to come up. It is an integral part of the system and shouldn’t be altered or defeated.

I suggest that you amend your file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

Reboot the computer and check:

```
ifconfig
```

Did you get an IP address? Can you ping?

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

If you get ping returns, you’re all set.

Comment: Nah, it goes deper that that. 
I copied your suggestion for the etc/network/interfaces - file. Rebooted, and lo and enp3s0 came up working.  So for the hell off it, I commented out the enp3s0 lines, and rebooted, and enp3s0 was back up ?!?. 

So I know lo is suppoused to be up, but my question is where are the config files controlling lo, and enp3s0 for that sake. It is obivous not the /etc/network/interfaceses file.

In fact I  just did a  
`sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.notworking`
Rebootet, and both interfacees are still up?

Comment: Let’s see: cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml Also: lsb_release -d

Comment: :~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes



~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Ah, haa! Not running 16.04 server edition then. By default, netplan manages interfaces in 17.10 server and later. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/976464/why-is-the-network-configuration-i-set-in-etc-network-interfaces-ignored-on-ubu/976497#976497