# how to restart network on setup shell

Tags: networking, server, live-usb

I have a ubuntu server 18.04 where I need to reinstall GRUB2 that got corrupted due to a bug.
The solution is to start the server with a live cd, download and install grub from the shell and reboot the server.

So I started the 18.04 installer, moved to the shell and edited /etc/network/interfaces to setup a static IP

Now I need to restart the network but none of the common methods work. How can I restart the network? I cannot restart the server since any change I do will get lost at reboot.

Edit:
For netplan I just have a file named `00-installer-config.yaml` and nothing else.
`ifdown` and `ifup` produce command not found each
what can I do?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "none of the common methods work"? There are many ways to restart your network (although not all available in when running live). What exactly did you try, and what was the result?

Comment: I suggest that the file you need to edit is in /etc/netplan. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/976464/why-is-the-network-configuration-i-set-in-etc-network-interfaces-ignored-on-ubu/976497#976497

Comment: @chili555 I know, but I just have 00-installer-config.yaml and not 01-netcfg.yaml 
Otherwise I'd have gone for this solution... it is the shell of the live cd and not an installed system

Comment: Are the correct details listed in your netplan file? If so, try: `sudo netplan generate` followed by: `sudo netplan apply` You should connect.