# cat /etc/network/interfaces No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, networking, server, 20.04, grub2

I just installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 in a VMware virtual machine. Now I am not able to use this command:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

as I am not able to see any network interfaces:

```
No such file or directory
```

How should I edit my `/etc/network/interfaces` and assign an IP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the default /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214170/whats-the-default-etc-network-interfaces)

Comment: The method `/etc/network/interfaces` is long since deprecated. Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/976464/why-is-the-network-configuration-i-set-in-etc-network-interfaces-ignored-on-ubu/976497#976497 Possibly a duplicate.

Comment: You could also use "ip" command to set IP temporary.

Comment: Use netplan. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 18.04 Ubuntu by default uses netplan to configure network.

Go to /etc/netplan, here you will find your network configuration.

It will look something like this:

00-installer-config.yaml

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```