# Wireless setup for server (netplan)

Tags: server, wireless, netplan

I've tried this solution: [Connecting to new Wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883305/connecting-to-new-wifi-network)
and looked here: https://netplan.io/examples

However, my interface isn't being assigned an ip or anything.

If I enter `networkctl` it shows that the device is stuck "configuring", as well as having "no carrier".

After I type `netplan apply` my wireless interface flashes its LED once and then nothing. I feel blind, is there a way to confirm it's attempting to connect to the network? What am I missing?

I've tried dhcp and separately, using static ip/gateway address in the .yaml file.

I've also confirmed the wireless device and network password are working by booting the same machine onto a desktop version of Linux and connecting to the network.

Comment: Did you modify the instructions to take account of the actual name(s) of the device(s) on your system (e.g. as shown by `ls /sys/class/net`)?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.